# Ошибка создания соединения soap

Tags: java, soap

код выдаёт ошибку на  `SOAPConnectionFactory soapFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();` самое начало функции.
Ошибка: `javax.xml.soap.SOAPException: Unable to create SOAP connection factory: Provider com.sun.xml.internal.messaging.saaj.client.p2p.HttpSOAPConnectionFactory not found`

Файл `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdk 32
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ddev.advanced_post_tracker"
        minSdk 23
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources.excludes.add("META-INF/*")
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.3'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'C:\\Java\\libraries\\OkHttp', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'C:\\Java\\libraries\\Jackson-DataBind', include: ['*.aar', '*.jar'], exclude: [])
    implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1'
    implementation 'javax.xml.soap:javax.xml.soap-api:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:saaj-impl:2.0.1'
    implementation 'com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj:metro-saaj:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

сама функция:

```
    private String Request(String trackNumber) {
        try{
            //Создание соединения
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection connection = soapFactory.createConnection();
            String url = "https://tracking.russianpost.ru/rtm34";

            //Содание сообщения
            MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance("SOAP 1.2 Protocol");
            SOAPMessage message = messageFactory.createMessage();

            //Создание компонентов сообщения
            SOAPPart soapPart = message.getSOAPPart();
            SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soap","http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("oper","http://russianpost.org/operationhistory");
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("data","http://russianpost.org/operationhistory/data");
            envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("soapenv","http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");

            SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();
            SOAPElement operationElement = body.addChildElement("getOperationHistory", "oper");
            SOAPElement dataElement = operationElement.addChildElement("OperationHistoryRequest", "data");
            SOAPElement barcode = dataElement.addChildElement("Barcode", "data");
            SOAPElement messageType = dataElement.addChildElement("MessageType", "data");


            //Заполнение сообщения
            barcode.addTextNode(trackNumber);
            messageType.addTextNode("0");

            //Сохранение изменений
            message.saveChanges();

            //Запрос и получение ответа
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = connection.call(message, url);
            Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
            try{
                Transformer t = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
                t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                try {
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                    t.transform(sourceContent, result);
                    return result.toString();
                }
                catch (TransformerException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
            }
            catch ( TransformerConfigurationException e) {e.printStackTrace();}

        }
        catch (SOAPException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "чёт не то";
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогла установка этих [jar файлов](https://download.jar-download.com/cache_jars/com.sun.xml.messaging.saaj/saaj-impl/1.3.6/jar_files.zip) вместо maven библиотек